# JSON: Showing several values from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I'm new with JSON and Javascript. I'm trying to figure out how to print all of these and not just one of them?

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
</script>
```

Comment: a `for loop` - or Array `forEach` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to duplicate @Davids answer, but a bit more to output all - add something like out variable to collect all the values and then output them:

```
var out='';
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
for(var i=0; i < obj.employees.length; i++ ) {

    out+=obj.employees[i].firstName + " " + obj.employees[i].lastName+'<br>';

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for-loop, you are just printing the values of index 1 in there maybe something like this should work

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.employees.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 
  obj.employees[i].firstName + " " + obj.employees[i].lastName + " ";
}
```

iterate over the object so you can add the values to the element :DD hope this helps

Comment: _never ever_ use the `+=` operator on the `innerHTML` of an element.   It causes the browser to serialise the current contents to a string, then append the new content to that string, and then _deserialise_ (i.e. recreate) all of the original elements again!

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the feedback, i honestly didn't know that

Answer (score -1):

You can show it in a loop.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < obj.employees.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
                        obj.employees[i].firstName + " " + obj.employees[i].lastName;
            }
```

NOTE: obj.employees.length = 3 (in this case)

Comment: same comment about about `innerHTML += ...`

Comment: @Alnitak oh, I wrote this answer at the same time the above answers. You can check it by look at the time I posted the answer. Then, please remove your bad mark on my answer. Regard!

Comment: I've downvoted all of the answers that use that syntax

Comment: (and FWIW they're all also wasteful for calling `getElementById()` within the loop)

Comment: @Alnitak Ridiculous. My purpose is only show to Ptree how to use JSON object. I do not emphasize how to use element HTML in this case.

Comment: In another case, you have to calling getElementById() within the loop. Ex: for (i = 0; i<5; i++) { document.getElementById('id_number_' + i); }. They are wasteful?

Comment: of course not, _if they apply to different elements_.

Comment: Yeah. I know. It is just a way to show data. My purpose is how to get the data. Not show them.

Answer (score -1):

If you ask me do it, i would do it like this. Code has been tested. Try it. I am using self executing function with strict check. Making using of javascript's prototype nature. I am assuming you have parsed JSON data and is available to use. Let me know if you need more explanation.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    var text = {
        employees: [
            {
                firstName:'john',lastName:'Dae'
            },
            {
                firstName:'Anna',lastName:'Smith'
            },
            {
                firstName:'Peter',lastName:'Jones'
            }
        ]
    };

    var Employee = function(data){
    //private vars goes here.
        this.employees = data.employees;
    };
    Employee.prototype.append = function(id_of_element){
        for(var i = 0;i<this.employees.length;i++){
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += '<li>'+this.employees[i].firstName+ ' ' +this.employees[i].lastName+'</li>';
        }
    };

    var emp = new Employee(text);
    emp.append();

})();
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
obj.employees.forEach(function(employee) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName + "\n";
});
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity (but not necessarily performance) use ES5's array methods:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
     obj.employees.map(function(employee) {
         return employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName;
     }).join('<br>');
```

or in ES6 syntax:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =
     obj.employees.map(employee => employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName)
        .join('<br>');
```

Note how both of the above avoid the repeated dereferencing of `obj.employees[i]`.

NB: this won't put a `<br>` after the final name, but if that matters you should be putting your list in a "block-styled" element which will implicitly move to the next line at the end for you.